# How can I protect my games?

Tags: security

How can I protect my game database/website from getting hacked by anyone?
And how can I prevent some hacks ingame, such as god mode and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first question would be better answered on superuser or somewhere like that. The second question is still very broad. "God mode" is something that developers implement, it's not a hack. Do some research on the topic and think about specific scenarios you think you need to protect against. There's no *correct* answer that could encompass all that you're asking here.

Comment: The second part of this question is valid I think because there are certain things that are worth keeping in mind about the ability to modify games running on your own systems.  You can hack in "God mode" via a number of ways without the developer ever creating that feature themselves.  I agree with @Byte56 though that with the first part you're going to get better results on superuser or somewhere that focuses on secure online interactions.

Comment: I'm going to try superuser then.
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: For your first question, it's off topic (not specific to game development) and you should do research on "system administration", but really you should first decide on a platform (Windows or Linux), software, etc. and look into administering each one. As for the second, you'll find many good questions and answers if you [search for cheating](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheating). After you read through those, then ask a specific question if you still have one. Also, please don't ask two questions in one. :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is far more important and difficult than a standard *1 million question*.

The answer is just under your nose and it's basically this: you can't and you are in an arms race.

There is a much more modern answer and it's: make it online and make it a service.

Games like Battlefield or Call of Duty are hacked and cracked but the fact that a big portion of their value is about online gaming on closed networks contributes to keep things under control even if the original game is hacked.

There is not even a viable approach to encription that can ensure you that your data is safe, you just need people working on this day by day in keeping your software up to date, no other real answers here if you care about your data.

If your users do not care about censorship and/or a limited amount of possibilities you can take alternative paths like the one taken by the games that i have mentioned before, but usually this requires a very good marketing approach.